# How fetch username of staff user in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, view, django-forms

I am using a custom User model. And I have another Customer model. I want the user field will only show the staff user no other type of user in the field will show in the registration form. In my case, it is showing all types of users whether it is staff or customer or a service user.

***Models.py***

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_Customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Service_Provider = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % self.pk

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

class Customer(models.Model):


    user = models.OneToOneField('accounts.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False)
    date_Of_Birth = models.DateField(null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Country', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='Country')
    state = models.ForeignKey('accounts.State', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='State')
    city = models.ForeignKey('accounts.City', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='city')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False)
    refernce_by_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    refernce_by_person_contact_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    alternate_no = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    hobbies = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

***views.py***

```
def form(request):
    forms = CustomerRegistrationForm()

    if request.method == "POST":

        forms = CustomerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            forms.save() 
            return redirect('/customer/show')

    context = {
        'forms' : forms,
    }

    return render(request,'customer/form.html', context)
```

***forms.py***

```
class CustomerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the staff users in the form like this.

```
class CustomerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):      
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=True))
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['user','email','date_of_birth',...]
```

Comment: Thanks, bro it fix the problem.